# pulkitjalan/google-apiclient[4.1.0, ..., 4.1.1] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.1.3) does not satisfy that requirement

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I installed a fresh copy of Laravel 9 and i attempted to install this package:

https://packagist.org/packages/revolution/laravel-google-sheets

But i get the following error when installing:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- pulkitjalan/google-apiclient[4.1.0, ..., 4.1.1] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.1.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
- pulkitjalan/google-apiclient[4.1.x-dev, 5.0.0] require illuminate/support ^6.0|^7.0|^8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- revolution/laravel-google-sheets 5.8.0 requires pulkitjalan/google-apiclient ^4.1||^5.0 -> satisfiable by pulkitjalan/google-apiclient[4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.x-dev, 5.0.0].
- Root composer.json requires revolution/laravel-google-sheets ^5.8 -> satisfiable by revolution/laravel-google-sheets[5.8.0].
```

My PHP version is 8.1.3 and it requires 7.2 and up - surely this should install as the PHP version is larger than what is required.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The required package `pulkitjalan/google-apiclient` isn't compatible with Laravel 9 currently. [A bug issue has already been opened](https://github.com/pulkitjalan/google-apiclient/issues/60). (also see [this](https://github.com/pulkitjalan/google-apiclient/pull/58) and [this](https://github.com/pulkitjalan/google-apiclient/issues/56)) So since google-apiclient isn't compatible, laravel-google-sheets isn't either

Comment: *"My PHP version is 8.1.3 and it requires 7.2 and up"* - No actually, `^7.2` means "Compatible with 7.2", not "Greater than 7.2"; that would be `>= 7.2`. PHP 8.1 is not compatible with PHP 7.2, so, as stated above, this package will not work with Laravel 9 (which requires PHP 8.0 at a minimum).